# Angular http.get request from https

Tags: angularjs, https

I faced the fallowing problem.

I have a request like this:

```
$http.get("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=" + latitude + "&lon=" + longitude + "&units=metric&appid=b0ef240f1eb180e6ccdcb22")
        .then(function(data) {
            $scope.weather = data.data;
            console.log('Weather request success', $scope.weather);
        }, function(err) {
            console.log("Weather request erroor");
});
```

It worked fine before I have bought SSL certificate.

Now I have an error in the console as fallows:

The page at 'https://www.vashagent.by/travel' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?lat=undefined&lon=undefined&units=metric&appid=b0ef240f1eb180e6ccdcb22'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

Comment: I hope you forget to change the URL address to https after you bought SSL certificate.

Answer (score 1):

Change the url from http://... to https://... $http.get. As the error indicates, you can't mix http and https on a secure site. There are other ways around it, but this is the most straight forward. openweathermap.org supports https.